# Can we set a color for timeline bar?

Tags: highcharts

I am creating a timeline chart and want to set explicitly a color to bar of timeline charts as attached in spac , how we can achieve it ?
[enter image description here][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JohRj.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `color` property for data points:

```
    series: [{
        ...,
        data: [{
            color: 'orange',
            ...
        }, {
            color: 'black',
            ...
        }, {
            color: 'red',
            ..
        }, {
            color: 'red',
            ...
        }]
    }]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9rybf43z/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.data.color